# How to edit list using thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety

I have a list and want to add some items to it.

The items that I want to add must be calculated which takes some time.
That's why I wanted to do it by a thread.

This is what I have so far:

```
 private void ManageBWPCList(BWPC pInput)
 {      
     BWPCList.Add(pInput);
 }

 private void FillBWPC(String[] computers)
 {
    foreach(String computer in computers)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => ManageBWPCList(GetBWPC(computer)));
        thread.Start();
    }
 }
```

This works in 1 of 4 cases.

Sometimes the list won't be filled or only get half of the items.

Any help is high appreciated.

Comment: you understand that putting calculation part in thread will make you code giving no guarantee that your list will have elements in some order ! right ?

Comment: Wrap accesses to your list in a `lock` or similar. Otherwise thread safety goes out the window and you see the results that you do (or worse)... Alternatively use a concurrent collection, like a `ConcurrentBag`

Comment: Why not use a `ConcurrentBag` instead of `List<>`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea to use a ConcurrrentBag. I never heard of that before but ill try using that.